# How to get accumulated render time of animation

Tags: rendering, animation, interface

When rendering an animation in the render window on the top right you can see the render time of the last frame. But where can I see the sum of the render times of all frames?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's an add-on called [Render Time Estimation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Render/Render_Time_Estimation) that will do that for you.

Full disclosure, I wrote that add-on.

Comment: Great! Why doesn't it ship by default with blender?

Comment: I've never pushed for its inclusion in trunk. I should probably clean it up a bit and do that.

Comment: Yes do that please. It's really usefull.

Answer (score 4):

1 - Move cursor over a progress bar, it displays Estimated and Elapsed time. But it disappears after rendering.

[image]

2 - or you can check file info and calculate total (elapsed) time from "created" to " modified" time, if minutes are enough for you. Like here rendering took 4 min.

[image]

Comment: That file trick is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think either answer addresses the question exactly - the poster wanted to know total render time already (not remaining), and for the whole animation, not for specific frames. I’ve written a plugin that gives you this exactly, which is free for personal use: https://blendermarket.com/products/total-render-time